# Excel formula with double quote with C#

Tags: c#, string, excel, double-quotes

I would like to write a formula in a Excel cell with SpreadSightLight in C#.
I have a following formula in excel

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!E:E, D2, Shet2!A:A, ">0")
```

In the code it looks

```
"=COUNTIFS({0}!E:E,{1},{0}!A:A ,\">0\")";
```

I save the file from the code, but when i try to open the file Excel (2013) gives error message and the formula is removed

> Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part

and the sheet3.xml contains the following line

```
COUNTIFS(Sheet2!E:E, D2, Sheet2!A:A ,&quot;&gt;0&quot;)
```

I tried the verbatim string and the char(34) solutions also but causes the same error.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it complete line of code? show one complete...

Comment: I have never heard of SpreadSightLight and so I googled it... I **only** got 5 results all pointing to only this question...

Comment: sorry @chancea I misspelled. It's called SpreadSheetLight.

Comment: Hi, @KazJaw. The complete line of code is: `string formula = "=COUNTIFS({0}!E:E,{1},{0}!A:A ,\">0\")";`  and the code to write:  `Write(string.Format(formula, sheetName, SLConvert.ToCellReference(StartRow, StartColumn + 2)), style2);` (where 'Write' is a own method to use 'SetCellValue' and 'SetCellStyle' together)

Answer (score 1):

I have not succeed to find the reason why there can be no double quotes written into an excel formula. However there is a solution to avoid double quotes:

> string formula = "=COUNTIFS({0}!E:E, {1}, {0}!A:A , CONCATENATE(CHAR(62), CHAR(48)))";

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody subsequently comes across this thread, I believe the problem is the greater than sign. It's getting confused with the end tag in XML. So it needs to be replaced by &gt (as hinted at by what you said your sheet3.xml contains).
I think the double quotes are fine as you have them - escaped with a preceding backslash.